# CheckBox button property strange result for 2.3.3 android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

Question: Why there is extra space in 2.3.3?

This is a strange behaviour that is why i thought i should ask. I got a checkbox in my xml and i have a background to set on it. so i put the background in its button property.

like `android:button="@drawable/back_checkbox"`

where back_checkbox is just a selector having checked/unchecked state

Now in 2.3.3:
[image]

And in 4.2:
[image]

Comment: So what is the problem...4.2 renders more properly than 2.3, is that what you are asking.

Comment: yes, i mean, why there is extra space in 2.3.3?

Comment: According to me, its because of the gravity which is default 'left' try setting it to "center_vertical" may be that can change the way things behave..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try **Toggle Button** instead.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/your_selector_xml"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff="" />
```

Comment: @Farhan.. Hope that its a better replica

Answer (score 0):

you must have the state checked and unchecked draw able in all of your xhdpi,hdpi,mdpi,ldpi folder with appropriate size

Comment: how can that play its part in solving the problem?

Comment: different API level device have  different screen density . higher api level device comes in hdpi and xhdpi category . so these devices the hdpi and xhdpi folder for finding drawable instead failing they use the maximum density from the given resource . So  I hope this will solve your problem . or post your full xml file for more elaboration